# Can't use .Union with Linq due to <AnonymousType>

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datagridview

I'm kind of stuck with that problem. Hope i'll get some help.
Here's the point.
I have to fill my DataGridView with that SQL request :

```
SELECT LOT.NumLot, EtatLot, NomEmploye FROM LOT
JOIN AFFECTATION_LOT on LOT.NumLot=AFFECTATION_LOT.NumLot
JOIN EMPLOYE on AFFECTATION_LOT.IdEmploye=EMPLOYE.IdEmploye
WHERE EtatLot='Libéré' or EtatLot='Suspendu' or EtatLot='Démarré'
UNION
SELECT NumLot, EtatLot, null FROM LOT
WHERE EtatLot='Démarré'
```

First i've used "null" value in my second "SELECT" because "UNION" need to have 3 arguments like the first "SELECT" and there is no "NomEmploye" data in my table LOT.
Anyway that request is working well in SQL.
But when i try to use it in LINQ

```
string test = "null";
var listeLotControle = (from x in entBoum.LOT
                        join aff in entBoum.AFFECTATION_LOT on x.NumLot equals aff.NumLot
                        join emp in entBoum.EMPLOYE on aff.IdEmploye equals emp.IdEmploye
                        where x.EtatLot.Contains("Libéré") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Suspendu") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
                        select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, emp.NomEmploye }).Union
                        (from x in entBoum.LOT
                        where x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
                        select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, test });
dataGridViewAffectationLotControleur.DataSource = listeLotControle.ToList();
```

I have that 3 errors in Visual Studio and i don't really understand it.

```
Error 1 Argument instance: can not convert 'System.Linq.IQueryable AnonymousType # 1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery <AnonymousType # 2>'
Error 2 'System.Linq.IQueryable <AnonymousType # 1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best overload the extension method 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union <TSource> (System.Linq.ParallelQuery <TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <TSource>) '
Error 3 type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList <TSource> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <TSource>)' can not be inferred from the use. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

As i can see, the problem is due to the `<AnonymousType>`.... But that don't help me so much right now.
I've also tried that way to make it work

```
IQueryable listeLotControle;
string test = "null";
listeLotControle = (from x in entBoum.LOT
                        join aff in entBoum.AFFECTATION_LOT on x.NumLot equals aff.NumLot
                        join emp in entBoum.EMPLOYE on aff.IdEmploye equals emp.IdEmploye
                        where x.EtatLot.Contains("Libéré") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Suspendu") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
                        select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, emp.NomEmploye }).Union
                        (from x in entBoum.LOT
                        where x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
                        select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, test });
dataGridViewAffectationLotControleur.DataSource = listeLotControle.ToList();
```

But i've got same errors plus that one

```
Error 4 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' was found (a using directive or an assembly reference is it missing?)
```

I maybe need a Using, but which one? (I precise that i already use `using System.Linq;`)

Finally i've tried that last method.

```
string test = "null";
var listeLotControle = from x in entBoum.LOT
                         join aff in entBoum.AFFECTATION_LOT on x.NumLot equals aff.NumLot
                         join emp in entBoum.EMPLOYE on aff.IdEmploye equals emp.IdEmploye
                         where x.EtatLot.Contains("Libéré") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Suspendu") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
                         select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, emp.NomEmploye };
var listeLotControle2 = from x in entBoum.LOT
                         where x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
                         select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, test };
var union = listeLotControle.Union(listeLotControle2);
dataGridViewAffectationLotControleur.DataSource = listeLotControle2.ToList();
```

But i still have these errors

```
Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable <AnonymousType # 1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best overload the extension method 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union <TSource> (System.Linq.ParallelQuery <TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <TSource>) 'contains invalid arguments
Error 2 Argument instance: can not convert 'System.Linq.IQueryable <AnonymousType # 1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery <AnonymousType # 2>'
```

Sorry for that big block but i've tried to explain all what i did before asking you.
Thanks for your future answers.

Comment: Good first-time question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your anonymous types are not the same type.

One is `{ ? NumLot, ? EtatLot, string NomEmploye }` and the other is `{ ? NumLot, ? EtatLot, string test }`. The last member has a different name hence it is a different type.

Try this instead:

```
var listeLotControle =
(
    from x in entBoum.LOT
    join aff in entBoum.AFFECTATION_LOT on x.NumLot equals aff.NumLot
    join emp in entBoum.EMPLOYE on aff.IdEmploye equals emp.IdEmploye
    where x.EtatLot.Contains("Libéré") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Suspendu") || x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
    select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, emp.NomEmploye }
).Union
(
    from x in entBoum.LOT
    where x.EtatLot.Contains("Démarré")
    select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, NomEmploye = test }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT! Now i know that i need the same name :) So i've done your way like this  `select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, NomEmploye = "Non affecté" }`

Comment: @Siick - As a newbie to community, you can visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and do accept the answer if that helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

When I only look at your last try I see this:

```
select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, emp.NomEmploye };
```

vs.

```
select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, test };
```

You can never assign or cast one list of anonymous type to another as long as all their properties do not have equal type and name.

EDIT: Write `select new { x.NumLot, x.EtatLot, NomEmploye = test };` for the second one instead.

Comment: Which explains the problem, but doesn't provide a solution.

Comment: @jessehouwing that´s true, I´ve updated one solution